# Function problems

Tags: python, function, loops, python-3.6

So I have two lists:

- `typeList` — list of strings of transaction types (addition, subtraction)
- `valueList` — List of values either added or subtracted.

as both value and type are appended to the list at the same index, I need to make a function to calculate the sum of the total value added and the total value subtracted, but I've been really stuck on it for ages trying to get my head around just how to do it. 
`desiredType` is just the type of transaction that is being looked for. As you'll see, I called my function twice with each type.
I understand that the index values need to be obtained and used between the two lists but not sure how to sum the values up.

```
def showInfo(typeList, valueList, desiredType):
     for i in range(len(valueList)):
         if typeList[i] == desiredType:
             total = total + valueList[i]
             return (total)
```

Call to the function:

```
 if choice == "I": #Prints transaction information
     print (showInfo(transactionTypes,transactionAmounts, "Addition"))
     print (showInfo(transactionTypes,transactionAmounts, "Subtraction"))
```

Any help would be appreciated as well as an explanation on how it's done.

Comment: Did you get any exception e.g. NameError?

Comment: Where is `total` first defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Please don't destroy content on Stack Overflow; by posting here you have licensed it's use to the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) together those 2 lists, then you don't have to keep track of the index you're looking at:

```
def transaction_total(types, amounts, desired_type):
    total = 0
    for transaction_type, amount in zip(types, amounts):
        if transaction_type == desired_type:
            total += amount
    return total
```

However, you're really just filtering values and summing them. Python makes this cleaner using generator expressions and the `sum` function:

```
def transaction_total(types, amounts, desired_type):
    return sum(amount for transaction_type, amount in zip(types, amounts)
               if transaction_type == desired_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep your data unmodified, you can just make your function more efficient (just one call) :

```
def showInfo(typeList, valueList):
     for i in range(len(valueList)):
         if typeList[i] == "Addition":
             total_add = total_add + valueList[i]
         else:
             total_sub = total_sub - valueList[i]
     return (total_add, total_sub)
```